# Native function in Mathematica export functions from Mathematica to MATLAB

Tags: functions, export, matlab

Is there any native function in Mathematica (not ToMatlab) that I can export a function from Mathematica to MATLAB, to Paraview or to any plotting software?

Clarification:
I want to export something like f[x_,y_,z_]:=Sin[x]Sin[y z] e^z;

Edit: Here why I want to move to MATLAB. I will have a 4D system and use ListPlot3D, SliceListPlot in Mathematica and I need to evaluate the function.

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := 
Cos[Pi*x^3] + Cos[Pi*x^3]*Cos[Pi*x^3] + Cos[Pi*z^3] + 
Sin[x + z] x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 
Exp[Cos[Pi*x^3] Cos[Pi*x^3] + Cos[Pi*z^3] + Sin[x + z] x^2 + y^2 + 
 z^2];
AbsoluteTiming[
data = Table[
Evaluate@N[f[x, y, z]], {x, 0, 1, 0.0025}, {y, 0, 1, 0.0025}, {z, 
 0, 1, 0.0025}];]
```

and Matlab version

```
x=0:0.0025:1;
y=x; z=x;
tic;[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(x,y,z);F = cos(pi*X.^3) + 
cos(pi*X.^3).*cos(pi*X.^3) + cos(pi*Z.^3) + sin(X + Z).*X.^2 + Y.^2 
+...
Z.^2 + exp(cos(pi*X.^3).*cos(pi*X.^3) + cos(pi*Z.^3) + sin(X + Z).*X.^2 
+ Y.^2 + Z.^2); 
toc;
```

Mathematica takes 37 seconds and MATLAB takes 14 seconds. I am aware the 37 seconds nothing but my function is much longer, it is 4D. 
[image]
Thanks.
Erdem

Ps: My functions are generally really long trigonometric functions.

Comment: Do you mean to export a function definition or to export some of the outputs of executing a function ?

Comment: To *any* plotting software? Is there a reason the plotting in Mathematica won't work for you? If you're really set against using Mathematica to do the plotting, you could check out MATLink. It allows you to communicate between MATLab and Mathematica.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I want to export the definition so they can evaluate the function however they want. Plot, add stuff, subtract stuff etc.

Comment: @MassDefect The reason I don't want Mathematica ploting seems to be too slow and plots are not something I can predefine (for my problem). The person I am going to give won't have access to Mathematica. He will run it via CDFplayer. Therefore, MATLink, ToMatlab is not an option for me.

Comment: @Erdem Oh, ToMatlab is a MATLink function isn't it. Sorry, I saw that in your question but didn't realize it was part of MATLink.

Comment: I have a function but only for polynomials.

Comment: How about you post an example of a slow plot, because Mathematica shouldn't be slower than Matlab for plotting. There are a number of ways you can speed up plots, including within a Dynamic environment.

Comment: @KRaZug I wasn't clear enough. I am planning to use the ListPlot options in Mathematica, therefore, I need to create  data and Table[Evaluate.... is 3 times slower even with a really short function.

Comment: "ToMatlab is not an option for me".  Did you look at what that package does? While the question is not very clearly phrased, as far as I can tell it does exactly what you want.  It converts expressions from Mathematica syntax to MATLAB syntax.

Comment: @MassDefect ToMatlab is not part of MATLink. It's a very simple package that can be entirely inlined into a CDF if needed.

Comment: If I compile your function, the table generation time goes from 34s to 6s.

Comment: `f4 = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {z, _Real}}, 
  Cos[Pi*x^3] + Cos[Pi*x^3]*Cos[Pi*x^3] + Cos[Pi*z^3] + 
   Sin[x + z] x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 
   Exp[Cos[Pi*x^3] Cos[Pi*x^3] + Cos[Pi*z^3] + Sin[x + z] x^2 + y^2 + 
     z^2], CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True, 
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]` gives me 5.7s instead of 34s.

Comment: @KraZug `Parallelization` is redudant here, it won't have any effect without  `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}`.

Answer (score 0):

Whether Mathematica is slow or fast does not really bother You. So the demand is to the HeavysidePi function. You ansatz is about alright. Continue use [Export MatLab Matrix](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MAT.html). Matlab is fast in importing and you can use the function values in 3D, 4D whatever You like. You friend has Matlab and can use the precompiled function value.

I am not deep into MatLab, but the name is short form of Matrix Laboratorium or similar. To be fast in functions the already use precompiled function definitions. So this path is simply following the strategies already used extensively in MatLab.

[HeavysidePi](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeavisidePi.html) is available in Mathematica in one, two and three dimensional input and probably can be used in even higher dimensionality.